# Install repo tool compatible with Python2 with init command

Tags: python, android, ubuntu-16.04, repo

What I'm trying to accomplish is to build Android 8 OS in docker container based on Ubuntu 16.04. To get sources I need to use repo tool. The latest repo was installed in Dockerfile.
When I do:

```
repo init -u git://git.osdn.net/gitroot/android-x86/manifest -b oreo-x86 -m android-x86-8.1-r6.xml
```

I get some Python syntax error, because this command installs the latest repo tool in ./repo which doesn't support default python in Ubuntu 16.

Then I try to add additional arguments to `init` to install 1.x version of repo instead of the latest, which will be compatible with python 2.7 or 3.5, with `--repo-url` option according to this [manual doc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man1/repo-init.1.html).

```
repo init --repo-url=https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/refs/heads/repo-1 -u git://...
```

And it says `fatal: remote error: Git repository not found`.
Then I try additional option `--repo-rev`:

```
repo init --repo-url=https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo --repo-rev=repo-1 -u git://...
```

I've got `main.py: error: no such option: --repo-rev`. I tried just:

```
repo init --repo-rv=repo-1 -u git://...
```

And got the same error.

**So my question is:** is it possible to install particular version of repo tool with
`init` command? And how to do it? How to define correct `repo-url`?

I've encountered this problem several times already and I always solved it by installing latest python version. But now I want to try different approach. And don't tell me to download wanted version with **curl**. I've seen how to do this, but I want to accomplish the same result with `init` command if it's possible.

Comment: First, download old `repo-1`: https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo-1

Comment: @phd I want to do it with `repo init` command

Comment: `mv repo-1 repo && repo init`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found answer myself.
I've found out that **repo** installed with **apt** is only launcher. And when `repo init` command is issued it installs full Repo tool. More about Repo tool you can read here: https://source.android.com/setup/develop#repo.

It turned out that **Repo** launcher's version from [docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man1/repo-init.1.html) which I referred to was older than currently latest version. And the option to download particular revision was changed. I looked through source code of latest **repo** version and found correct option.

So to download 1.x version of Repo with `init` command use this option:

```
repo init --repo-branch=repo-1 -u git://...
```

And this version will be compatible with old Python versions from 2.7 to 3.5.